# How to launch iOS emulator from Xamarin Studio

Tags: xcode, xamarin-studio

Just beginning to use Xamarin Studio.

- Purchased the indie addition
- Uploaded all the certs and provisionning profiles
- Compiled the entire solution

Now I would like to run the iOS part of the solution in iOS emulator. The problem is - I'm unable to find where in Xamarin Studio is the link or menu option to launch an iOS emulator. I also have the latest Xcode installed on the same Mac machine. So, how do I go about running the compiled iOS project in an emulator?

-Eugene

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, all I had to do was to switch the Project configuration from Debug to Debug iPhone Simulator: Project ->Active Configuration -> Debug iPhone Simulator.